# Audio player progress iOS

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I am playing an audio clip using AvAudipPlayer, I want to know if there is a way to get progress on how much time is left or played ?
I want to animate the slider control while the audio is being played in a view is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read [AVAudioPlayer's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html). You'll find that the player has two properties that pertain to this, `currentTime` and `duration`

```
audioPlayer.currentTime

audioPlayer.duration
```

Then, assuming that you're leaving your sliders min and max values at their default settings (0 - 1), you can determine progress by simply dividing `currentTime` by `duration`.

Comment: ok i thought there might be some delegate which will get called on progress, anyways thanks!